# WiFi turns off in host when running Kali Linux in VirtualBox

Tags: linux, wireless-networking

My TP-LINK TL-WN722N WiFi adapter installed correctly in the host computer using drivers from the CD. But once I turn on Kali Linux, WiFi adapter turns off and doesn't work anymore. When I close Kali Linux, it works again. How may I fix this?

Comment: Have you checked for updated drivers online and installed them?

Comment: check in VBox settings/VM settings whether you have a bridged connection setup - bidge will disable the network for the host system.

Answer (score -1):

for anyone checking this years later like I was, when you enter kali the usb adapter gets transferred over as if its been plugged into the virtual machine and taken out yours if you have no internet passed that point in the kali machine then that means your wifi drivers hasn't been installed correctly this link is what I followed and mines works just fine. https://www.hackster.io/thatiotguy/enable-monitor-mode-in-tp-link-tl-wn722n-v2-v3-128fc6

Comment: Welcome to Super User! Please quote the essential parts of the answer from the reference link(s), as the answer can become invalid if the linked page(s) change.